# Task Not Serializable - Serialization behavior Change between Spark 2.4 and Spark 3.x

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, serialization, kryo

We are migrating our spark jobs from 2.4.5 to 3.1.1 (scala 2.11.11 to scala 2.12.13)

We are facing the following exception

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:416) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:406) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2465) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1(RDD.scala:912) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:911) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:749) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
```

And this triggered when we use map, flatMap, cogroup (with some functions) on a Dataset.
For instance, here is the signature of a function we use to map a dataset to another dataset:

```
def myFunction(var: (Seq[caseClass1], Option[caseClass2], Option[caseClass3])): (Seq[caseClass2], Seq[caseClass3], Seq[caseClass2], Seq[caseClass3])
```

The code did not change. We use KryoSerializer and the configuration is almost the same.

It used to work in Spark 2.4.5.

We've found a work-around to make my job work. We wrap it into the following function:

```
def genMapper[A, B](f: A => B): A => B = {
  val locker = com.twitter.chill.MeatLocker(f)
  x => locker.get.apply(x)
}
```

As follows

```
DS.map(genMapper(myFunction)) // This works
// DS.map(myFunction) -- This does not work
```

Yet I really want to understand what is fundamentally different in serialization behavior between Spark 2.4.5. and Spark 3.x ..

Thank you

Comment: Hello! Have you found a better solution?

Comment: It might have something to do with the scala version as spark 2.4.5 uses scala 2.11.x. and spark 3.x uses scala 2.12.x and there are some differences between scala 2.11.x and scala 2.12.x

Comment: Could you explain more @NikunjKakadiya ?